# Let $I$ be the ideal generated by the polynomials $p(x)=3$ and $q(x)=x^3-x^2+2x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ a domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I think it is true!... but I don't know how to prove it. Someone help me please.

Comment: Is $q(x)$ irreducible over $\Bbb F_3$?

Comment: It would help to have some context of what level you're at.  For example, we could answer $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I \simeq \mathbb{F}_3[x] / \langle x^3 - x^2 + 2x + 1 \rangle$ which is a domain if and only if $x^3 - x^2 + 2x + 1$ is irreducible as a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_3$, but it's hard to be certain if that would be a helpful answer.

Comment: the context is not clear?

Comment: I'm afraid your questions are magnets of negative attention. Please [study our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619), and fix them. For example, A) you have a strange idea of what should be in the title and what should be in the question body, B) the questions are lacking in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x^2-1)(x-1)=x^3-x^2-x+1=q(x)-3x=0$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]/I$, and $x^2-1$, $x-1$ are not $0$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]/I$, so the ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]/I$ is not a domain.